# Is Python a fixed-field formatted language?

Tags: python, format

So I'm a bit of a newbie even though I've been coding basic stuff for a while now, and I just want to ask if Python is written in a fixed-field format or a free-field format.

From information on the internet, most fixed-field formatted languages are very old, and some links as well as ChatGPT say Python is considered a free-form language, however, Wikipedia and some other links say otherwise as well. There are not many articles explaining this. Any help, please?

Comment: What do you mean by a "fixed-field formatted" language?  Do you mean a language such as [RPG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_RPG) where the code is written according to a very strict format layout?

Comment: Classic Fortran was a fixed field language.

Comment: *"Wikipedia and some other links say otherwise as well."* - Specific citations please!!

Answer (score 1):

The more conventional terms for this are fixed-form vs free-form; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free-form_language.

In fact, the Wikipedia page (currently) says:

> *"Structured languages exist which are not free-form, such as ABC, Curry, Haskell, Python and others."*.

To me, that<sup>1</sup> says that Python is neither fixed-form or free-form ... but a third category.

If I were put on the spot ... I would argue that the third category is a subset of free-form.  But that is just my opinion.

Having said that, there is no *authority* to say what the precise definitions are<sup>2</sup>.    So different people will have different opinions.  In this case, the "debate" is (IMO) largely waste of time.  It doesn't really matter how we classify the languages.  Python is what it is, irrespective of peoples' attempts to classify it.

---

<sup>1 - More precisely, this is what the *authors* of the page are saying. But as noted, they have no *authority*.  Indeed, the page doesn't cite any primary sources to back up what they say.

2 - As far as I am aware ....</sup>